# Python, install .pyd file: ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python

I am trying to install the PyLZJB.pyd file from here:

```
 https://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/downloads/list
```

I have downloaded the file and placed it in my Python27/DLLs folder where I also see some other .pyd files. I am on Windows.

I have tried

```
import PyLZJB.pyd
```

and

```
import PyLZJB
```

Based on another answer I also tried:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Python27\DLLs")
```

before the import.

I continue to get the message:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only dlls built for Python-2.6 in the site.

You cannot use dll built for Python2.6 in Python 2.7.

Find the dll built for your system (platform, python version should match). Or build it yourself.